# CFML if/else statement acting weird under Coldfusion 6

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I have the following very simple if/else statement:

```
<cfif Server.ColdFusion.ProductVersion GTE "7">
        <cfoutput>#encrypt("Test text", "77qidrWFoQg96taobooCm3/WimS2Gcdd", "DESEDE", "Hex")#</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
        <cfoutput>#encrypt("Test text", "77qidrWFoQg96taobooCm3/WimS2Gcdd")#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Works at it should under CF 7, 8, 9, 10 but not under CF 6 where I get the following error like it doesn't care about the `<cfif>` tag and executes what is meant for the greater versions of CF (>7).

[image]

Any idea? I tried many many many different otions and same result. CF 6 make me despair.
P.S. No, my clients I write some scripts for are not going to move to a later version yet.

Comment: Shouldn't you be extracting the major product version as a number and comparing it to `7` rather than `"7"`, as "7">"10" but 7<10? Although I don't see why that would go wrong with CF6. Have you tried reversing the conditional?

Comment: I tried also `cfif Server.ColdFusion.ProductVersion GTE 7`, same result; I tried also `<cfset coldfusionVersion=Replace(Replace(ListDeleteAt(Server.ColdFusion.ProductVersion,4),",","","all")," ","","all")>` and then `<cfif coldfusionVersion GTE 700>` with same result :-|

Comment: I tried even `<cfif Server.ColdFusion.ProductVersion LT 7>` with same result, CF 6 just ignores my `<cfif>` and executes code not meant for its version...

Comment: What happens when you cfdump Server.ColdFusion.ProductVersion ?

Comment: It takes 4 parameters in CF 7 -> 10, is not relevant, I just wanted to use a function not found in CF 6 as an example. This come must work in any CF versions that's why...

Comment: What if you hard-code a `6` instead of using `Server.ColdFusion.ProductVersion`, just for a quick test? Your `coldfusionVersion` variable does not appear to be a number.

Comment: cfdump Server.ColdFusion.ProductVersion: `6,1,0,63958` and under CF 10: `10,0,0,282462`

Comment: With `<cfset coldfusionVersion=Replace(Replace(ListDeleteAt(Server.ColdFusion.ProductVersion,‌​4),",","","all")," ","","all")>` I make it a number and is the same error I get.

Comment: Side note, if you are comparing strings, do not expect it to behave like a numeric comparison. Use list functions to extract the major version, then compare it as a number

Comment: To all... it has nothing to do with the conditional, although it won't work as written.  It just won't compile because of how encrypt is being used.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ColdFusion is trying to compile the page, but it cannot because you are using an invalid syntax for the `encrypt` function.  CF 6 does not allow those arguments to be passed to `encrypt`.  I suggest if you need to support CF6 that you use a `<cfinclude>` statement to include the post-CF6 code. So something like:

```
<cfif listfirst(server.coldfusion.productversion) gte 7>
  <cfinclude template="cf7encrypt.cfm" />
<cfelse>
  <cfinclude template="cf6encrypt.cfm" />
</cfif>
```

Then in the two cfm files you can include the version specific calls to encrypt. Then it will compile properly.

Another option would be to have two different CFCs that act as wrappers to encrypt (one for CF6 and one for CF7+) and then load the proper CFC and call an encrypt function.  In either case, the key is to get the invalid call to `encrypt()` out of the main template.

Comment: Nope, I can use encrypt(), is irrelevant here, I can put say `notexistingfunction()` and I get the same result. The problem is with the `<cfif>`

Comment: Read the error message you are getting.  It says its a parameter error for encrypt.  Encrypt does not support more than 2 arguments on CF6.  Just because you wrap it in a CFIF does not mean it doesn't get compiled.  It is not the conditional.  Trust me.

Comment: Compilation and runtime errors are two different things.  You are getting a compilation error.  Again, you can't use invalid code and just wrap it in CFIF and think everything is going to be OK.  CFIF controls program flow during execution.  It doesn't excuse invalid syntax.

Comment: Yes but why it even looks at it because I have the `<cfif>`? That's the problem, it should just skip it and go for `<cfelse>` like any other programming language on earth does.

Comment: It looks at it because it is a compiled language.  The page gets compiled into Java byte code then executed.  It cannot compile syntax it does not understand and it does not understand passing more than 2 arguments to encrypt.

Comment: Ah, got you. If you do if/else in Perl, Python, Ruby, C or whatever is different. And is different under CF 8, 9 or 10 also, it just skips if there's an if/else condition.

Comment: Only interpreted languages function like that.  In a compiled language all the code is read at once, compiled and then executed.  In an interpreted language the parser follows the code logic line by line and throws an error at runtime if necessary.  You are getting an error at compile time.

Comment: .. ie so it has nothing to do with the `cfif`. compilation != execution

Comment: In C, Java, etc other compiled languages it will be exactly the same. Python and ruby are interpreted.  Hence the difference.  Feel free to research the difference on your own.  At some point CF allowed you to provide more arguments than a function expects and it will just ignore them.  However, that is different than what I am explaining.  8, 9, 10, etc still will compile the code down to Java byte code first and invalid syntax will still throw a compile time error.  However, they changed it so that extra arguments are no longer "invalid syntax".  I do not recall what version made that change

Comment: Yeah, seems you're right, code was ok under CF 8, 9, 10 because they know `encrypt()` with two arguments also so syntax was ok.

Comment: Just to reinforce what Sean and Leigh are saying: they're exactly right. The entire file needs to be syntactically valid for the ColdFusion version that it's being compiled by. And... erm... it does actually even SAY it's a compile (/parse) error at the top of the stack trace, dunnit?

Comment: CF10 allows 2 arguments for backwards compatibility.  So 2 arguments will work fine on CF10.  Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: The problem is with the second line of code on CF6 (4 arguments) not the 4th line (2 arguments) on CF7+.  That is why you get the error on CF6 and no error on CF7+.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will encapsulate the `encrypt()` with 4 arguments meant for CF >7 in some variable and load it :)